# How to use Spring for dependancy injection in a java program

Tags: java, spring

I want to use Spring for DI in a java program. I have some classes like configurations classes and clients classes that I would like to inject, but I do not want to create a Tomcat serveur and I want to be able to write my program in the main function like a do usually.

I tried to play with the application context but without success (as you can guess).

Here is a two class codes to reproduce :

```
package com.alltests;

import com.socionodes.alltests.Config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
@Component
public class App 
{
  @Autowired 
  public static Config config;

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    System.out.println("conf obj is : ");
    System.out.println(config);
  }
```

```
package com.alltests.configs;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Configuration;

@Configuration("config")
public class Config{
  private String user;

  public String getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
```

and pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.alltests</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-spring-di</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test-spring-di</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.alltests.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

an properties.yml:

```
config:
  user: me
```

The goal is to have the Config object in config automatically. Is this possible ?

Comment: "*I do not want to create a Tomcat serveur*" Then why have you have included spring-boot-starter-**web**?

Comment: You don't need Spring Boot Server, for DI, you can use Spring Core functionality which includes Spring Core, Context, Spring Beans.

Comment: @Michael you are right, i just stick with what i know but this is stupid, ty.

Comment: @Sambit ty, I look into it, but still I would be happy to have an exemple of how to create the application context with those dependancies.

Comment: All solved, thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

There are many contrived statements in your question. I'll try to explain.

First of all I suggest figuring out whether you want to use a spring boot at all. It looks like you do (by placing `@SpringBootApplication` annotation) however inside the `main` method you're trying to create a context that comes from a regular spring world.

In spring boot there is no point of doing so, it will prepare an application context for you.

Now, if you don't want to create a tomcat - its possible in spring boot, in this case you don't need to include `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in maven.

Spring boot in general can run non-web-based (read with tomcat, jetty ,etc) applications:

Here is an [example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-non-web-application-example/)

If you opt for "plain" spring - in its core meaning it provides a DI container. So you won't have any tomcat there.

All-in-all it looks like you don't really understand the difference between plain spring and spring boot (sorry if I'm mistaken, it just looks like this from your question and provided code snippets)

Comment: You are not mistaken at all. I think regular spring is good enough. The only interest in spring boot I see is, I think, automatic component scanning, but it comes with many things that I don't understand and I don't want to spend too much time on. I just want DI for a few objects in a regular java program. I'll look into regular Spring, ty.

Comment: Regular spring also has component scanning although it doesn't establishes rules on what packages should be scanned  - you should specify the package to be scanned by yourself.From your comment it looks like you need a regular spring for now.